# How to scale a torus and keep the radius of tube unchanged?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, graphics

If I have a torus defined like this.

```
u,v are in the interval [0, 2π),
R is the distance from the center of the tube to the center of the torus,
r is the radius of the tube.
```

I want to enlarge the R and keep r unchanged, how to use transformation matrix to do it, or is it possible?

Comment: Is the torus actually defined by polygons? If not the if you need to enlarge R, just do so. For example multiply it or add to it...

Comment: Express the points of your torus in a coordinate system where the center of the torus is at the origin and you can assume that a plane at height zero (z = 0, for example) bisects the tours laterally. Compute every point's projection into this plane and express the projections in polar coordinates. Then translate the radial coordinate.

You cannot just multiply or translate coordinates from your original torus because then the relative distances won't be preserved. You have to work in this radial-coordinate only after you project everything into a plane.

Answer (score 0):

The transformation you're looking for is not linear, so it can't be represented by a matrix.

To tell that it's not linear, imagine the torus centered at the origin laid out parallel to the xy-plane. The positive x-axis intersects the torus at two points; let's call the one closer to the origin `a` and the farther one `b`.

After you apply your transformation, we expect that `a` and `b` both moved away from the origin by the same amount. But since `b` is a multiple of `a`, this is impossible:

```
b = c*a
f(b) - b = f(c*a) - c*a
         = c*f(a) - c*a
         = c*( f(a) - a )
```

The same multiple that relates `a` and `b` also relates how far `a` moved compared to `b`.

You will have the same problem even if you project the torus onto a plane.